# iOS Find Location (Latitude,longitude) from Zipcode

Tags: iphone, geolocation

What could be the best way to get location for a given zipcode. Would it work for countries outside US/Canada .Thanks

Comment: You can find location by providing the address of that location

Comment: For future reference pleas refer to here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606031/ios-mkmapview-place-annotation-by-using-address-instead-of-lat-long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Google geolocating API (try it out on google.com/maps):

Input for a Swiss ZIP code for example:
CH-9014

or a french one:
FR-34000

or german:
de-12101

or US:
us-90210

or canada:
ca-J5Z 1A1

or china:
cn-100000

for [example](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ch-9014&sensor=false):

yields

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "postal_code" ],
    "formatted_address": "9014 St Gallen, Switzerland",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "9014",
      "short_name": "9014",
      "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "St Gallen",
      "short_name": "St Gallen",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Sankt Gallen",
      "short_name": "SG",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Switzerland",
      "short_name": "CH",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 47.4082855,
        "lng": 9.3323890
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 47.3991076,
          "lng": 9.3180504
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 47.4199564,
          "lng": 9.3543340
        }
      },
      "bounds": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 47.3991076,
          "lng": 9.3180504
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 47.4199564,
          "lng": 9.3543340
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

So the swiss ZIP code 9014 corresponds appx. to this location:

```
"lat": 47.4082855,
"lng": 9.3323890
```

See my answer on the geolocating API here:
[How to get GLatLng object from address string in advance in google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534142/how-to-get-glatlng-object-from-address-string-in-advance-in-google-maps)

Comment: @Jagdish: My code? Yes. The google-api for commercial intranet purposes: no.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org) offers a number of various zipcode geocoding services, including search for the location of a given zipcode. They support a number of various countries.

You would probably be most interested in the [Placename Lookup for postalcode service](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#postalCodeLookupJSON)

Comment: I just found this [site](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/) on GeoNames. It offers files for different countries with the mapping of the zip code to the lan/long values. Now, I can create a batch process and store all required values in my database, being able to loop up lat/long values for a given zip code. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

Google's API comes with some fairly nasty restrictions. Better to use open sources like GeoNames per @Claus Broch's suggestion.

I'm adding this answer to also note that MapQuest has recently put up an API to OpenStreetMap data. It doesn't do (as far as I can tell) zip code searching, but location names, directions, altitude etc are all freely queryable. I recently discovered it an I plan on replacing my calls to google maps API with it as soon as I can.

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'fairly nasty restrictions' ?

Comment: There are limits on the number of calls you can make in a day, is one. The bigger deal is, you are only allowed to use their api in conjunction with showing a Google Map. So using it purely in the background as the data-gathering tool it is isn't allowed.