# Retrieve place name based on latitude and longitude

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want the blackberry code to retrieve a place name based on latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it from Google maps api.

Example:
[iOS Find Location (Latitude,longitude) from Zipcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646155/find-latitude-longitude-from-zipcode/4646283#4646283)