# How do you use CLRegion in iOS 7 since initCircularRegionWithCenter:radius:identifier: is deprecated?

Tags: ios7, cllocationmanager, clregion

Since the depreciation of `initCircularRegionWithCenter:radius:identifier:`, how would you define the region to be monitored using `CLLocationManager`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since `CLCircularRegion` is a subclass of `CLRegion`, you can just cast the instance.

```
CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:theCenter
                                                             radius:theRadius
                                                         identifier:theIdentifier];

// Then cast the instance for use with your CLLocationManager instance
[manager startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region];
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what is the max recommended radius for them?

Comment: I would stick with a radius between 1 and 400 meters unless Apple update their docs stating otherwise.

Comment: CLCircularRegion inherits from CLRegion, so I don't think a cast is necessary. But other than that, I agree: you replace the deprecated method by creating the CLCircularRegion subclass with its initializer and using that in place of a CLRegion.