# Xcode Swift - View entered Postcode on Apples map

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i'm after for some help please!

I've got a textField called 'textFieldPostcode' and a `UIButton` called 'btnViewOnMap'

my idea is that when the user enters their postcode into the `textFieldPostcode`, and presses `BtnViewOnMap` button, it will take the user to Apples Built in maps and show the postcode that was entered.

I've seen a few tutorials on how to open Apples build-in Maps with code, which works

**Code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldPostcode: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var btnViewOnMap: UIButton?
```

**ViewDidLoad()**

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewOnMapPress))
    btnViewOnMap?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Function for the **viewOnMapPress:**

```
func viewOnMapPress(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if (buttonError != nil)
    {
        SVProgressHUD.showErrorWithStatus(buttonError?.localizedDescription)
    }
    else{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?")!)

    }
}
```

the line below opens the maps, and shows a location, but how can i change this so that it searches for the users input instead ?

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?")!)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (send postcode as query parameter to map):

```
let stringURLSearchPostCode = "http://maps.apple.com/?q=" + self.textFieldPostcode.text
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: stringURLSearchPostCode)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this documentation, it contains examples of Apple Maps queries that search location in the Maps app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

But the problem here is that most likely Apple Maps don't search by ZIP-code.
So at first you need to get location coordinates or address of postcode entered with the help of third-party API.

You may find example here

[iOS Find Location (Latitude,longitude) from Zipcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646155/ios-find-location-latitude-longitude-from-zipcode)